# Copy an N-Index column of a Pandas Dataframe including all sub-headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

This question expands off of a previous question of mine:
[Copy a Multi-Index column of a Pandas Dataframe including the second header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72652509/5178442)

**EDIT -** Clarifying that one of my issues deals with the discrepancy when `N=1` (produces an `Index` dataframe) and when `N>1` (produces a `MultiIndex` dataframe...)

**Background -** I have a dataset with `N` headers that I've read from a CSV. `N` can be anything greater than *or equal to* 1...

e.g. `N=1`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0:N])
print(df)

     A   B   C 
---------------  (Single-)Index dataframe
0    1   2   3
1    4   5   6
2    7   8   9
       ...
```

e.g. `N=3`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0:N])
print(df)

     A   B   C
     a   b   c
     ɑ   β      
---------------  MultiIndex dataframe
0    1   2   3
1    4   5   6
2    7   8   9
       ...
```

**What I Want -** I'd like to duplicate one of the columns (say, ***A***) into a new column ***D***, such that its sub-headers are copied as-is for an arbitrary (`N`) number of index headers...

```
     A   B   C   D
  ...N header rows...
     a   b   c   a
     ɑ   β      ɑ
----------------------
0    1   2   3   1
1    4   5   6   4
2    7   8   9   7
       ...
```

**Current Solution -** ...based on answers to my [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72652577/5178442) question, I can do this with a fixed number of header rows, `N`...

e.g. `N=2`:

```
df[('D',df['A'].columns[0])] = df['A']
```

But this won't work for a normal, single-Index dataframe, since `df['A']` won't have a `.columns` attribute...

**Need For Extension -** ...I'm unsure what the most pythonic way to handle `N` rows might be... presently I've made an `if` case for `N=1` and `N=2`, but that feels clunky...

I wonder if there's a way to force a single-`Index` dataframe to be a `MultiIndex` dataframe with a single index row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
df[('D',) + df['A'].columns[0]] = df['A']
```

```
print(df)

   A  B  C  D
   a  b  c  a
   ɑ  β    ɑ
0  1  2  3  1
1  4  5  6  4
2  7  8  9  7
```

If there is multiple second level columns under `A`

```py
df[[('D',) + col for col in df['A'].columns]] = df['A']
```

```
print(df)

   A     B  C  D
   a  b  b  c  a  b
   ɑ  β  β    ɑ  β
0  1  0  2  3  1  0
1  4  0  5  6  4  0
2  7  0  8  9  7  0
```

Comment: Thanks @Ynjxsjmh! I think I should be more clear in my question (I'll edit):

Sometimes, I have a MultiIndex dataframe, and sometimes I have a single Index dataframe. Your method will work for every instance EXCEPT for when I have a single Index (NOT multiindex) dataframe... does that make sense?

Comment: @MoTrip Use a if else to judge if it is multiindex.

Comment: Thanks again! As of right now, that's where I'm at... the only issue is that (I believe) the method you proposed requires 3 if/elif/else cases: 

(**1 Header Row**) Index

(**2 Header Rows**) MultiIndex but ```df['A'].columns``` is not iterable

(**3 or More Header Rows**) MultiIndex with iterable ```.columns```

Comment: @MoTrip For 2 or more header rows, you can use `df[[('D',) + tuple(col) for col in df['A'].columns]] = df['A']`, but I think it needs extra steps to judge 1 header row.